# equivalence relations proof and equivalence classes

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

Let $X$ be a non-empty set, and let $R$ be an equivalence relation on $X$. Let $C$ be the set of all equivalence classes of $R$. So $C = \{A \subseteq X$ such that $A = [x]$ for some $x \in X\}$.

Now, define $f : X \rightarrow C$ by the rule $f(x) = [x], \forall x \in X$.

Prove that if $x \in X$, then there is one and only one equivalence class which contains $x$.

Suppose $X = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$ and that $R$ is an equivalence relation for which $1\,R\,3$, $2\,R\,4$ but not $1\,R\,2$, $1\,R\,5$, and $2\,R\,5$.

Write down the equivalence classes of $R$ and draw a diagram to represent the function $f$.

Comment: If $x\in A\in C$ and $x\in B\in C$, then for all $y\in A$ and for all $z\in B$ you have $(x,y)\in R$ and $(x,z)\in R$. Since the relation is an equivalence relation, we get that $(y,x)\in R$ (symmetry) and therefore $(y,z)\in R$ (transitivity since $(y,x), (x,z)\in R$). Therefore $A=B$.

Comment: @deyore then how do you find the equivalence classes of R

Comment: I am not clear what $R$ is. Is $(2,5)\in R$? Is everything after the 'but not' pairs that are not in $R$?

Comment: @deyore yes, everything after the but not are pairs that are not in R

Comment: Then the classes are $c_1=\{1,3\}, c_2=\{2,4\}, c_3=\{5\}$, and $f(1)=f(3)=c_1$, $f(2)=f(4)=c_2$, and $f(5)=c_3$.

Comment: @deyore so would that be included in the diagram to represent the function f?

Answer (score 0):

C = { [x] : x in X }.
If x in [a], [b], then x equivalent a and x equivalent b.
Thus a equivalent b, whereupon [a] = [b].